# Setting a root directory for accessing files from subfolders?

Tags: php, html, localhost, document, root

I am trying to create a root directory on my localhost(using xampp) so that I can link to images and folders found on the root from subfolders. So my directory is built like seen below.

Also, would this method work when the site is uploaded on the web? or would I have to change document root to http:// links to my site?

F = folder
f = file

```
My Site
-------
[f] index.html
[f] logo.html
[F] css -> [f] main.css
[F] news -> [F]1 -> [f] 1.html
[F] images -> [f]logo.jpg
```

logo.html will be included using PHP on every html page.
So if I include the logo.html in both index.html & news/1/1.html link to image doesn't work since the news file is on a different folder and link to the images folder changes.

I tried this using PHP but it seems I am doing it wrong:

```
<?php $root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/My Site/'; echo $root .'/images/logo.jpg';
?>
```

Comment: When you say you what to "link" to them, do you mean like an `<a href="">` type of a link (an *anchor*)? If so, you should use relative paths, `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` is definitely not what you want. For example `<a href="images/logo.jpg">`

Comment: Relative wouldn't work since the link for logo.jpg from 1.html would have to be href="../../images/logo.jpg" I must use same link without switching dirs, that's why I want to create a root.

Comment: *Why* must you do this? There is rarely a good reason for not using relative paths. Not doing so is likely to break portability.

Comment: Because relative links do not work :) I edited my main post, you will probably understand what I was trying to say now.

Comment: Well use absolute paths then (`<a href="/images/logo.jpg">`)

Comment: As I said on Cfreak that is not working. I am inside logo.html and using img src="/images/logo.jpg" isn't working. Only images/logo.jpg works(without slash on the beginning)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` gives you the real file-system path, not the path returned by Apache.

To link to the resource you need to use the HTTP path. If you want to link from the root you just need something like `/images/logo.jpg`

Comment: Read my main post again, I edited it. logo.html contains images/logo.jpg. If I include logo.html in news/1/1.html then the link to the image doesn't work. How to fix that?

Comment: add the preceding `/` which will then start from the document root no matter where the file appears.

Comment: then there is some other problem. Are you accessing the site through `http://localhost/My Site` or through `http://localhost/`?

Comment: Yeah that works! But what happens when uploaded to the web? I suppose I will need to change every /My Site/ with the http:// link? Is there an easier way for this?

Comment: This goes outside of programming and more into system stuff but what I'd do is create a virtual host locally. In your hosts file you can add an entry like `mysite.local  127.0.0.1` then set up mysite.local as a VirtualHost and point it's DocumentRoot directive at `/full/path/to/My Site`.

Answer (score 0):

I found that on my `PHPBB3.1` driven website using the "Pages" addin, the relative link would not remain 'static' in some link buttons at the top of my site.

From the `PHPbb3` index page a link such as app.php/page/FT would produce an address of `http://earth/forum/app.php/page/FT` (Correct) ,but from the "Pages add in) that same link produced `http://earth/forum/app.php/page/app.php/page/FT` (incorrect).

I started looking for a way to set my page relative to the root of the web. I could NOT use absolute links because my site is replicated on other servers. I found the answer by trial and error. Simply add several ../../../ like this ../../../forum/app.php/page/FT
and it works.

Perhaps not the best of computer programming but it does the job. 
In a nutshell with each ../ you step back a directory, put too many in and it goes back to the root but cannot go back any further!