# Change root directory only for a set of files

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, localhost, root

I have this structure in my localhost (I use Apache2 and Ubuntu):

```
/var/www/

-- PROJECT1
---- index.php
---- layout.php
---- etc.

-- PROJECT2
---- index.php
---- layout.php
---- somefile.php
---- ADMIN
-------- index.php
-------- etc.
---- CSS
-------- main.css
```

*(The ones with CAPITALS are folders)*
So, when I'm in the root of the project, I can use links correctly if I want to refer into some  file, for example, if I'm inside `index.php` from the PROJECT2, I can do this:

```
<a href="somefile.php">Click here to go to some file</a>
```

And this will actually refer the user to the `somefile.php` file. But if I'm inside the admin folder, this doesn't work, so I tried to put a slash before the file, so it would be like this:

```
<a href="/somefile.php">Click here to go to some file</a>
```

But no, this actually refers to the path `/var/localhost/somefile.php`.
So, I wonder if there's a way to change the root path with a code or something like this, because I'd like to have the path for project1 like `/var/www/PROJECT1` and for project2 like `/var/www/PROJECT2`.

I've also found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12786588/setting-a-root-directory-for-accessing-files-from-subfolders), but it actually changes the root directory for all the projects I have.
So, what can I do?

Thanks!

## Found the solution

Hi, I found the solution!
What I did, is adding a line of code in my header, and now it works perfectly. This is what I've used:

```
<base href="/project1/">
```

Answer (score 1):

Look into virtual hosts. That way for different projects you can have different hosts defined which is a better way to separate them. Also all your project then will live in a root of their virtual hosts

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I found [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts), is this what I have to do? Is it a good tutorial? Thanks! ;)

Comment: I've never read this particular one, so give it a try and if you can't make it work - and tried to look into the official documentation you can always ask for help here

Comment: Hey! I've done it but actually, when I go to `http://localhost/project1/admin` and try this `<a href="/somefile.php">Click here to go to some file</a>`, it doesn't work.

Comment: Okay, found the answer. I've put this in my header: `<base href="/project1/">`, and now it works! By the way, thanks for helping!